# How do I create my own package in Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I want to develop a **Umbraco package**. Where do I have to start and Where do I have to end?
I have knowledge on **Asp.net MVC 4** and using the **Umbraco cms** as a user

Answer (score 0):

A package is quite a broad definition. A package can for example be an extension to Umbracos back office, but can also simply consist of nodes.

There is plenty of guides and documentation on Umbracos website.

Read more here, for example https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/extending/

This should definitely be where you have to start. Where you have to end is hard to say, because it depends on the package you want to create.

Comment: How are the things organised? Viz.. MVC.. Like to create an MVC application I just have to create a new project in visual studio and put the code with respect to front end - controller - database... How I can accomplish the same? Here,.,. Actually we are integrating a package to the existing umbraco interface,.,. That means an extra view, controller... Can you tell me if this is architechture they are following too?

Comment: Not knowing which type of package you're wanting to implement in Umbraco, makes it hard for me to answer your question. But Umbracos backoffice is built with AngularJS. It's not like creating an MVC application in Visual Studio, there's other things you need to be aware of. The best advice I can give you, is to look at the documentations.

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Extending/